# Show last line on previous indentation level at all times in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to keep the last line in each indentation level above the cursor on the screen, so that I can get a better feeling for where in the nested blocks I am?

For example, this python snippet:

```
def a():
    if b:
        return 1
    if c == d:
        if k == p:
            ...
            return x + 1
    if k < x:
        return 2
```

If my screen doesn't show anything above the `...`, and the cursor is at `return x + 1`, I'd like to see this overlayed on the top of the screen:

```
def a():
    if c == d:
        if k == p:
```

I think there's a similar feature where it shows just the line the function you're in is declared on, but I cannot find it right now.

This is language-agnostic, and can work on indentation level rather than syntax tree.

Answer (score 0):

The similar feature you mean is called View | Context Info. There is no feature to do exactly what you want.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in the menu on PyCharm, but pressing "alt+Q" to activate it still worked. No wonder I didn't find it at first :)